# Перевести дробное число из 10 сс в 2 сс с++

Tags: c++, union

Требуется написать программу на с++ для перевода чисел типа double и float из 10 сс в 2 сс двумя способами: classic и union.
Классик я уже реализовал, т.е. разбил число на целую и дробную часть, нашел экспоненту и посчитал мантиссу.
С union все намного сложнее, гугл не помогает. Есть догадка, что нужно объеденить вещественное число и массив чаров, но как именно не могу разобраться.
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Что такое `union` способ?

Comment: Как [пример](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-conversion-of-32-bits-single-precision-ieee-754-floating-point-representation/). `union` способ подразумевают собой разделение дробной и целой части при помощи логично `union`. По приведенной ссылке есть пример `union` способа. Хотя не очень понимаю т.к. вы пишите "_объеденить вещественное число и массив чаров_".

Comment: Типы уже физически храняться в двоичной системе. Что за задача перевести из десятичной? Поточнее задачу поставьте.

Comment: Большое спасибо Павлу, очень хороший пример, помогло разобраться